# Data Science option does not appear when I am in IBM Watson Studio

Tags: ibm-watson

I am taking a course offered by IBM on Machine Learning and I am given the following instructions:

> Sign in into Watson Studio and import your notebook Sign in into
>   https://www.ibm.com/cloud/watson-studio Click on 'New Project' Select
>   'Data Science' as type of project.

However when I click on New Project the option 'Data Science' does not appear.  There are four Options but not 'Data Science' among them.

[image]

Comment: If your account is free, and you didn't create it in US-South, you may get different results. Also once created, you will be locked to that region until you upgrade the account, or create a new account in US-South.

Answer (score 2):

You are missing the entitlement service for Watson Studio which why you do not see the other options.
Go to Settings in Watson Studio
For US South
https://dataplatform.cloud.ibm.com/settings/services?context=analytics&nocache=true

If you are in other region, simply click Settings from top-right circle.
[image]

Under Apps Tab -> Click Add Apps or simply click Add other Apps from top-right box under the account drop-down

[image]

Click Try it for Free -> Select the plan you wish to add

[image]

Click Create.

[image]

Click Confirm to Create Watson Studio Service.

Once the service is created,
At landing page, you will see the options you are looking for

[image]

Hope this helps.

Comment: I've created a youtube video on that process https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bf0GpmgOYbk

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to contact support, because you should be something more like -

[image]

Answer (score 0):

ignore the template, click "new project" -> new empty project, fill the name of the project. Then the following is all the same.

Why:
Data Science experience has been renamed as Watson Studio.

ref: https://www.coursera.org/learn/machine-learning-with-python/discussions/weeks/6/threads/_rcBnPuBEem2-gr7TnpXlw