# Watson Studio : No Envirionment option or Notebook

Tags: jupyter-notebook, ibm-watson, watson-studio

I created a watson studio account. Then, I created a new project, however, I do not have access to the environment, bookmark and deployment option. Furthermore, when I go to asset and click on add to the project, only the options data, connection, connected data, dashboard are present

Thank's for you're help

[Project Dashboard](https://i.stack.imgur.com/igbbE.png)
[Add asset menu](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1l7TH.png)

Comment: Possible duplicate of this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61957237/why-i-cant-see-notebook-in-project-watson-studio/61975283#61975283

Comment: Possible duplicate of this as well https://stackoverflow.com/a/52488030/5629418

Answer (score 0):

If you want to work with Notebook then first create that Project and then create a new Notebook from the same top-right corner from where you have created the project. While creating the project there will be an option to choose in which project you want to add the Notebook. Choose your desired project name